# Authenticating by Request Header in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, http, authentication, request, header

I'm developing an intranet application that will be hosted behind an appliance that performs user authentication, then adds a unique user identifier to the header each authorized request it passes through. Which is to say, all the hard stuff is already done.

How can I configure ASP.NET Core to utilize the supplied header? User accounts with the associated request header are accessible from Entity Framework, but it's an Oracle provider, with a nonstandard schema. I'm using .net 5.0.
I assume this is relatively simple to implement, but I've been digging through documentation for a couple days and so far I've only found things that don't quite do what I need.

I'm not looking for a complete solution, just hoping to be pointed in the right direction. I'm not confident that what I've written so far is correct, but the project I'm experimenting on is based off the `dotnet new mvc --auth individual` starting template. Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i get the question right, all the hard stuff was gone and now we just need to pull related information based on a given `userId`.

If that's the case, I would recommend to define your own `AuthenticationMiddleware`, that would not doing anything related to validate the user, but rather to pull user information from some where and cache it(with a reasonable expiration and clear cache by key mechanism).

Then, every request came after, just took the info from cache then build our own `User` object that would stick to each `HttpContext`. This is the final result we should aiming to.

All the process that should make use of `AuthenticationSchemeOptions` and `AuthenticationHandler` to build our own authentication middleware. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authentication-handler) would be good for a starting point.